# How can I make the text of my button been perfectly aligned vertically?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Good day,

I have two buttons with an up and down arrow, as shown in my picture below.

[image]

The corresponding html code is the following :

```
[...]

<tr>
  <td class="tablerows" height="40">lab01 - Temp&#233;rat. pi&#232;ce [T1]</td>
  <td class="tablerows"><input id="lab01" type="text" name="country" class="resizedTextbox" value="20" readonly>
    <a href="#" class="myButton" onclick="TemperatureControl('lab01','decrease')"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="myButton" onclick="TemperatureControl('lab01','increase')"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
</td>
</tr>

[...]
```

*Edit, thanks to your help. However, I am still not able to align all my elements, as I would like*

The linked CSS is the following :

```
td{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.myButton {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
    background-color:#3e12cc;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;

    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:18px;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #154682;
    width:20px;
    height:25px;
    vertical-align:-1px;
    line-height:auto;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background-color:#0061a7;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
.resizedTextbox {width: 50px; 
height: 20px;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border-color:#3e12cc;
text-shadow:0px 1px 1px #154682;
background-color:#f5effb;
vertical-align:text-top;
text-align:center;
font-size:18px;
}
progress {
  background-color: #0061a7;
  border: 0;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 9px;
}
```

What I am basically trying to do is to have a 'good' vertical alignment (in my example, we can see that it's not very well aligned).

Before annoying you - and risking a negative downvote - I tried to google my problem, but I could not find the issue that I am having. Am I missing a property or did I set it incorrectly ?

Thanks for your hints

Comment: For a PERFECT alignment, the best way IMO is flex-box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to align it with

```
vertical-align:-6px;
```

Try this it should work. Please share a codepen going forward, so that its easier for others

Comment: 1000 thanks - it works perfectly. Can I ask you quickly another question? If now I would change the width of the button to 30px, what do I need to have it centered horizontally?

Answer (score 3):

Use this css, removed height and width and added `box-sizing`

```
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding:10px;
```

```css
.myButton {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
  background-color: #3e12cc;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #154682;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="#" class="myButton" onclick="TemperatureControl('lab01','decrease')"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="myButton" onclick="TemperatureControl('lab01','increase')"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add line Height for `.myButton`

```
line-height:25px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `vertical-align:middle`. Try it and tell me if works, otherwise, you can add `padding-top:` for separete it from top.

Comment: Thanks but I was not able to solve the problem. For the padding top, isn't it equal to the line 'padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;' ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your very quick replies. The solution provided by Gowtham Shiva helped me a lot, although many other ones that I upvoted are perfect.

Finally, here is the contents of my css file :

```
td{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.myButton {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
    background-color:#3e12cc;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;

    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:18px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #154682;
    width:20px;
    height:25px;
    vertical-align:-6px;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background-color:#0061a7;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
.resizedTextbox {width: 40px; 
height: 20px;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border-color:#3e12cc;
text-shadow:0px 1px 1px #154682;
background-color:#f5effb;
vertical-align:text-top;
text-align:center;
font-size:18px;
}
progress {
  background-color: #0061a7;
  border: 0;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 9px;
}
```

Hope this post will help someone in a similar situation.

Have a good week-end.